# How to do a CONTAINS query in Calabash with React-Native

Tags: react-native, calabash

I am trying to get up and running with Calabash for a React-Native app.

I can do this query successfully:

```
query("RCTView marked:' Coaching'")
```

But there are multiple views with this unfortunate spacing. I would like to do a contains query instead.

I have tried a few variants without success, for example:

```
query("RCTView {label CONTAINS 'Coaching'}")
```

But this does not work.

This is what the view looks like from the first query's result:

```
    [
    [0] {
                       "alpha" => 1,
                     "enabled" => true,
                          "id" => nil,
                     "visible" => 1,
                       "frame" => {
                 "y" => 0,
                 "x" => 0,
             "width" => 75,
            "height" => 50
        },
        "accessibilityElement" => false,
                       "class" => "RCTView",
                       "label" => " Coaching",
                 "description" => "<RCTView: 0x7ff38205a2e0; reactTag: 474; frame = (0 0; 75 50); layer = <CALayer: 0x600000228080>>",
                       "value" => nil,
                        "rect" => {
                   "y" => 617,
            "center_x" => 262.5,
            "center_y" => 642,
                   "x" => 225,
               "width" => 75,
              "height" => 50
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you could try:

First would be, to ask the dev to remove the spacing :).

In case both " Coaching" and "Coaching" are needed for some reason, use this:

```
query("RCTView")[0]['label'].include? 'Coaching'
```

Here you are going through the hash and checking if the label includes whatever you want it to include, in this case "Coaching".

Try using '*' instead of the class name:

```
query("* { label CONTAINS 'Coaching' }")
```

If that doesn't work on any label, consider this:

```
def contains_label(label)
  hash_to_use = query('RCTView')
  hash_to_use.each do |key|
    if key['label'].include? label.to_s
      hash_to_use[hash_to_use.index(key)]
    end
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!